# c# create list of class with generic type

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have a class Named `FieldConnector<T>` which accepts many types as generic (T) (string, int,...)

How can I create a List in C# without specifying T like:

```
var x = List<FieldConnector<????>> = new List<FieldConnector<????>>();
```

Comment: A type has to either be specified or unambiguously inferred, neither of which can happen on the line of code shown.  Why can't you specify the type?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You need to have `T` define in the class your current line is or `T` must be defined in your method signature

Comment: Do you mean to have a double assignment in your example??

Comment: I can only agree with the other comments but if you really want to have a multi-typed list you can use the object type (FieldConnector<object>). In the rest of your code, you’ll probably understand why it’s a bad idea ... and I’m not even mentioning the boxing/unboxing penalty

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a class you could use an interface. Either you define your own interface or use an existing one. Furthermore, you can use T and the where clause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

Answer (score 0):

C# is a type safe language, which prevents you from doing what you are trying to do here. **For your own safety.**

Look at the following situation where `T` is just a type parameter:

```
List<T> myList = new List<T>();
myList.Add(10);
myList.Add("Banana");
// Some more calls to Add ...

var myItem = myList[7];
```

What type is `myItem`? Since `T` is not a type, that can't be the answer. If you try to pass it into a function, how would the compiler know you are not doing something "illegal" since the underlying type might not match the functions parameter?

So by not specifying a type you prevent the compiler from warning you when you are about to do something that doesn't work.

---

What you really should do is think about why you are trying to do this and then ask how to obtain that goal.

Comment: It works if you use `object` instead of `T`

Answer (score 0):

As long as the method or class containing the assignment you're attempting is also generic, you can re-use the type `T` from there:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        List<FieldConnector<T>> x = new List<FieldConnector<T>>();
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class Foo
{
    public void Bar<T>()
    {
        List<FieldConnector<T>> x = new List<FieldConnector<T>>();
    }
}
```